# Eclipse - Python and Ipython?

Tags: python, eclipse, ipython

I'm following along a book about the use of python for finance. And the author uses this line:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Which does not compile.

So far I've figured out that it's Ipython that is being used, and that it's another interpreter than the python.

I'm using Eclipse with pyDev, and I'm looking for a solution so that I may continoue doing so.

I installed ipython through pip with `pip install ipython` and top of my .py file write

```
import IPython.ipapi 
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()
```

But I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\PythonFinance\src\FinanceExamples.py", line 5, in <module>
    import IPython.ipapi
ImportError: No module named 'IPython.ipapi'
```

the `ip = IPython.ipapi.get()` does not give any errors. But if I comment out  `ip = IPython.ipapi.get()` then it will.

Is it not possible to run Ipython with a python interpreter? Or have I missunderstood the entire relationship between them both.

I use python 3.5

Comment: Commenting because I'm not sure how to _answer_ your question. While there are certainly parts of IPython that can be leveraged as individual modules, [IPython](https://ipython.org/index.html) itself is intended to be a more interactive (e.g. tab completion, some syntax coloring) alternative to the traditional Python shell. `%matplotlib inline` which you mention first is a so-called "magic" used in [Jupyter notebooks](http://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to force plots/figures (e.g. from matplotlib) to show up inline when using the notebook interface.

Comment: Ah there no way to use the "magic" in Eclipse?

Comment: Cell "magics" aren't really a feature of Python, but rather just a nice feature of the IPython shell so unless you can invoke an IPython shell in eclipse (I don't use eclipse so I don't know if this is possible), these cell "magics" won't be of any use to you. However, [spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/index.html) is a python IDE that gives you an IPython console inside the editor. The IPython/Jupyter notebook (see link in my first comment) also provide nice interactive Python environments but are not as full-featured as an IDE like eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Open Eclipse/PyDev and go to Window-->Preferences-->PyDev-->Interactive Console. 
In the Initial Interpreter Commands filed add this 2 commands:

`import IPython; IPython.embed()`

After clicking in Apply and Close, press `CTRL+ALT+ENTER` (or select the code that you want to execute +`F2`) and IPython console will run. However, it seems not work very well. You will face on the message below if you try to run `%matplotlib inline` command:

```
IPython.core.error.UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'inline', valid ones are:dict_keys(['qt4', 'osx', 'pyglet', 'none', 'tk', 'qt', 'gtk3', 'glut', 'wx', 'gtk'])
```

Comment: This helped me but it also throws the warning `UserWarning: Failed to get module unknown module global_ns.get('__name__', 'unknown module')`, any idea what that is?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use IPython interpreter in Eclipse/PyDev interactively - in a PyDev Console. (You can start it in the Console Menu. More: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html.)
2. You don't need to add any extra lines to your file. All magic commands are usually executed in the console. (I think extra code is needed only if you want to run some magics in a script, not interactively). You can run your code line by line copying it from the editor or - faster- highlighting it and pressing F2.
3. The command `%matplotlib inline` probably wouldn't work in PyDev Console. It's designed rather for IPython Notebook. Nevertheless, try running it there and you should get some error with a hint what to use instead "inline", for example:

   ```
   IPython.core.error.UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'inline', valid ones are:dict_keys(['qt4', 'osx', 'pyglet', 'none', 'tk', 'qt', 'gtk3', 'glut', 'wx', 'gtk'])
   ```

   Also, you get some help displayed when you execute `%matplotlib?` (with the question mark).

Answer (score 0):

tried with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and run

```
plt.show()
```

Looks like that gives the same results.